# melancholically or melancholic

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

In the example below, should I use melancholically or melancholic? Are either fine to use?

"the music begins playing melancholically/melancholic over the dancefloor."

Thanks for any input, much appreciated :)

Comment: "melancholically" suits your sentence, but sounds awful.  Alternatively, "the melancholy (melancholic) music begins to play across the dance floor" should be fine as well. Phrases like 'a touch of melancholy', 'air of melancholy' may also be considered in alternative formations.

Comment: "[Music] begins to play across the [...] floor" is generally incorrect usage. I can only think of very specific contexts where this would work well.

Comment: And, what would those contexts be... if you don't mind?

Comment: thanks for your help @NoviceInDisguise, would it make any difference if it were: "the national anthem begins playing melancholically over the dancefloor." instead of "the music"? Is this correct usage? Also thanks for your input sankarane :)

Comment: While being slightly awkward, I think it would be correct.

Comment: Or maybe "Melancholy music suffuses the air above the dance floor"?

Comment: 'melancholically' may well be a legal construction out of root and suffixes, but in that sentence there are too many things going on. The personification of music is too much.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use melancholically if you want in that place, without changes to the sentence structure. As the sentence is right now I would not use melancholic, as that is the wrong form, but with editing it could be a useable alternative.

If you really want to use melancholic, then I would suggest the following, although without context it is hard.

> The music begins playing in a melancholic mood, sorrowfully wafting over the dance floor.

Basically, melancholic is an adjective, and has to describe a *noun* or *pronoun*. `Over` is not either of these, so it would be incorrect usage. You need to edit the sentence to include one of these if you want to use that word.

Comment: "melancholy mood' is also correct.

Comment: That is correct

Answer (score 0):

**melancholic** is an *adjective*, while **melancholically** is an *adverb*.

You can use an adjective to describe a *noun* - eg the the music, the way I feel, the style of the music

eg.

> The music was melancholic. (Describing the *music*).
>
> The music made me feel melancholic. (Describing *the way I feel*).
>
> He played the music in a way that was melancholic.  (Describing the *way*).

You can use an adverb to describe a verb eg. the act of performing music, or a metaphorical literary device.

> He melancholically strummed his guitar. (Describing the act of *strumming*).
>
> The music melancholically drifted over me. (Describing the act of the music *drifting*).